# why cant i replace __add__ with __radd__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am (for exercise) trying to make a class that works with roman numerals. I am trying to put as much functionality into it as possible, so i looked into making operators work on them. I found (example, the problem persists among other pairs of methods) `__add__` and `__radd__`. The documentation says that if `__add__` is not defined it (or if it fails) looks into `__radd__`, but when i try to delete `__add__` and edit the `__radd__` method it works on `0 + myobject`, but not on `object1 + object2`.

Here is the class (with a few things cut out because they're not important for my problem):

```
class Roman:
    num_map = [('M', 1000), ('CM', 900), ('D', 500), ('CD', 400), ('C', 100), ('XC', 90), ('L', 50), ('XL', 40), ('X', 10), ('IX', 9), ('V', 5), ('IV', 4), ('I', 1)]

    def __init__(self, num=None):
        self.decimal = 0
        self.roman = 'N'
        if type(num) == type(0):
            self.__setattr__('decimal', num)
        elif type(num) == type(''):
            self.__setattr__('roman', num)


    def __setattr__(self, field, value):
        if field == 'decimal' and type(value) == type(0):
            super().__setattr__('decimal', value)
            super().__setattr__('roman', self.dec2roman(value))
        elif field == 'roman' and type(value) == type(''):
            super().__setattr__('roman', value)
            super().__setattr__('decimal', self.roman2dec(value))
```

The methods `self.dec2roman(integer)` and `self.roman2dec(string)` simply convert from one format to the other.

Now if i try to make `__radd__` like this:

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    if other == 0:
        return self
    return Roman(self.decimal + other.decimal)
```

it doesn't work, but this does:

```
def __add__(self,other):
    return Roman(self.decimal + other.decimal)
def __radd__(self, other):
    if other == 0:
        return self
    return self + other
```

Here's the error i get:

```
>>> from roman import Roman
>>> a = Roman(3)
>>> b = Roman('X')
>>> a + b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Roman' and 'Roman'
```

Does someone know what is going on?

Comment: But Python got roman numeral literals since v2.4 ..  see [PEP 313](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0313/) (p.s. check the date of the PEP)

Comment: yea i know, this was simply an experiment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the “data model” section](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) of the Python documentation,

> [`__radd__` and similar functions] are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation **and the operands are of different types.**

(Emphasis added.) This is why defining `__radd__` is not working for you: you’re trying to add two items of the *same* class. I’m not sure why you’re trying to avoid `__add__` but that method is clearly what is called for in this situation.

Comment: I missed that line... Thank you for the quick response! The idea was to make it so that i can use `sum()` on it

Answer (score 1):

The `__radd__()` method is called only if your object is the right hand operand. You can see this by simply printing the `__doc__` of this item for integers:

```
In [4]: (1).__radd__.__doc__
Out[4]: 'Return value+self.'
```

And You can check this behavior using an example:

```
In [7]: class A:
   ...:     def __radd__(self, other):
   ...:         return 10
   ...:     

In [8]: a = A()

In [9]: a + 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-429dec850246> in <module>()
----> 1 a + 2

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'A' and 'int'

In [10]: 2 + a
Out[10]: 10
```

But when you are using two of these objects python calls the first objects `__add__` method and that's why it raises the exception. If you want to get ride of that you can simply handle the problem inside the `__add__` method instead of writing a logical code for it.

For example you can use the `other` as the right hand operand in order to use the `__radd__` inside the `__add__`:

```
In [24]: class A:
             def __radd__(self, other):
                 return 10
             def __add__(self, other):
                 return 5 + other
   ....:     

In [25]: a = A()

In [26]: a + 2
Out[26]: 7

In [27]: 2 + a
Out[27]: 10

In [28]: a + a
Out[28]: 10
```